# UIButton not highlighting when it is dynamically created

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a dynamically created UIButton in my table's `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. It loads fine, and it can be selected, but it doesn't do the highlight animation when it is selected. I tried adding:

`if(commandButton.isHighlighted)`, and that didn't trigger when selected. Here's how I load the cell:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString* CellIdentifier=@"CommandCell";
    UITableViewCell* commandCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIButton* commandButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:commandCell.frame];
    [commandButton setTitle:@"Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [commandCell.contentView addSubview:commandButton];
    commandButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    return commandCell;
}
```

Whenever I click on it, `commandButton` is not highlighted...

**EDIT**: it was a stupid problem, I wasn't holding down my mouse for long enough. For those of you who have a similar problem, simply press down on the button for longer in the iOS simulator.

Comment: where are you using this : commandButton.isHighlighted ? is it some other function ?

Comment: That brought to my attention that I was putting it in the wrong place. I'll fix it. But still, I'm not seeing the highlight animation anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may this help you add the bellow code into ur code

if you want to so some image on tuchupinside then below code.

```
[commandButton setBackgroundImage:/*add you image using UIImage*/forState: UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

if you want simple (default background color when it appear in button on tuchupinside).

```
UIButton *buttonTap=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
```

and set the frame like this

```
buttonTap.frame=commandCell.frame;
//make some adjustment as per requied.
```

if u want some blur type effect(semi partial on selection )
Then you go for

```
UIButtonTypeCustom //type
```

Comment: Hey Carpetfizz i dont know what you want,i had edited my answer you can look up it..may help you

Answer (score 1):

The `UIButton` that you create in the following line

```
UIButton* commandButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:commandCell.frame];
```

is a **custom** styled `UIButton` by default. For this button, you will have to set all the properties *manually*. What you want is this:

```
UIButton *commandButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
[commandButton setFrame:cell.frame];
```

The `UIButtonTypeSystem` contains the style that you are looking for.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where are using this ? but still my suggestion is to give a tag to the button if you are adding it to the cell like :

```
UIButton* commandButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:commandCell.frame];
[commandButton setTitle:@"Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
commandButton.tag = 1;
[commandCell addSubview:commandButton];
commandButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

and while accessing the same button ;

//you have to get the cell where button has been clicked

```
   UIButton *button =(UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
```

and on this button you can use :

```
if(commandButton.isHighlighted)
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you add button to cell view, try to add:

```
NSArray * views = [commandCell.contentView subviews];
for (UIView *object in views) {
    [object removeFromSuperview ];
}
```

Because maybe u have multiple cells one on other, so the button is actually clicked is the "most bottom cell view" button.

Comment: Try to add target @selector for commandButton for all EventStates and NSLog all touch-event states that it receives. Maybe because of tableView it doesn't receive the touchDown events, so you will know the root cause.